Server Side DataTables warning: table id=DataTables_Table_0 - Ajax error
I'm getting an error when trying to setup a datatables with my project.
DataTables warning: table id=DataTables_Table_0 - Invalid JSON response. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/1
This is my index.php:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.24/css/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.css">

    <title>Kontak</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    
  <div class="container mt-5 mb-5">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-12">
        <h1>Data Entry</h1>
      </div>  
    </div>
    <hr>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-12">
        <div class="table-responsive">
          <table class="table table-striped table-sm">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th scope="col">No</th>
                <th scope="col">Tipe</th>
                <th scope="col">PBF</th>
                <th scope="col">Tanggal</th>
                <th scope="col">Nomor Faktur</th>
                <th scope="col">Nomor Gudang</th>
                <th scope="col">Nilai</th>
                <th scope="col">Jenis</th>
                <th scope="col">No. SP</th>
                <th scope="col">Setor</th>
                <th scope="col">No SPJ</th>
                <th scope="col">No Verif</th>
                <th scope="col">PPK</th>
                <th scope="col">Verif</th>
                <th scope="col">Bayar</th>
                <th scope="col">Aksi</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              <!-- List Data Menggunakan DataTable -->              
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <hr>
  </div>

 
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.24/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.24/js/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.js"></script>



<script>
      
      $(function(){

           $('.table').DataTable({
              "processing": true,
              "serverSide": true,
              "ajax":{
                       "url": "ajax/ajax_kontak.php?action=table_data",
                       "dataType": "json",
                       "type": "POST"
                     },
              "columns": [
                  { "data": "no" },
                  { "data": "tipe" },
                  { "data": "pbf" },
                  { "data": "tanggal" },
                  { "data": "faktur" },
                  { "data": "noGudang" },
                  { "data": "nilai" },
                  { "data": "jenis" },
                  { "data": "sp" },
                  { "data": "setor" },
                  { "data": "nospj" },
                  { "data": "noverif" },
                  { "data": "ppk" },
                  { "data": "verif" },
                  { "data": "bayar" },
                  { "data": "aksi" },
              ]  

          });
        });
</script>
</body>
</html>

this is ajax_kontak.php:
<?php 
require_once '../koneksi.php';

if($_GET['action'] == "table_data"){


        $columns = array( 
                                0 =>'id_entry', 
                                1 =>'tipe',
                                2 => 'pbf',
                                3 => 'tanggal',
                                4 =>'faktur', 
                                5 =>'noGudang',
                                6 => 'nilai',
                                7 => 'jenis',
                                8 =>'sp', 
                                9 =>'setor',
                                10 => 'spj',
                                11 => 'noverif',
                                12 =>'ppk', 
                                13 =>'verif',
                                14 => 'bayar',
                                15 => 'id_entry',
                            );

        $querycount = $mysqli->query("SELECT count(id_entry) as jumlah FROM entry");
        $datacount = $querycount->fetch_array();
    
  
        $totalData = $datacount['jumlah'];
            
        $totalFiltered = $totalData; 

        $limit = $_POST['length'];
        $start = $_POST['start'];
        $order = $columns[$_POST['order']['0']['column']];
        $dir = $_POST['order']['0']['dir'];
            
        if(empty($_POST['search']['value']))
        {            
            $query = $mysqli->query("SELECT id_entry, tipe, pbf, tanggal,
                                            faktur, noGudang, nilai, jenis,
                                            sp, setor, spj, noverif,
                                            ppk, verif, bayar
                                             FROM entry order by $order $dir 
                                                                        LIMIT $limit 
                                                                        OFFSET $start");
        }
        else {
            $search = $_POST['search']['value']; 
            $query = $mysqli->query("SELECT id_entry, tipe, pbf, tanggal,
                                            faktur, noGudang, nilai, jenis,
                                            sp, setor, spj, noverif,
                                            ppk, verif, bayar
                                             FROM entry WHERE tipe LIKE '%$search%' or
                                                              pbf LIKE '%$search%' or
                                                              tanggal LIKE '%$search%' or
                                                              faktur LIKE '%$search%' or
                                                              noGudang LIKE '%$search%' or
                                                              nilai LIKE '%$search%' or
                                                              jenis LIKE '%$search%' or
                                                              sp LIKE '%$search%' or
                                                              setor LIKE '%$search%' or
                                                              spj LIKE '%$search%' or
                                                              noverif LIKE '%$search%' or
                                                              ppk LIKE '%$search%' or
                                                              verif LIKE '%$search%' or
                                                              bayar LIKE '%$search%'
                                                                        order by $order $dir 
                                                                        LIMIT $limit 
                                                                        OFFSET $start");


           $querycount = $mysqli->query("SELECT count(id_entry) as jumlah FROM entry WHERE tipe LIKE '%$search%' or
                                                                                            pbf LIKE '%$search%' or
                                                                                            tanggal LIKE '%$search%' or
                                                                                            faktur LIKE '%$search%' or
                                                                                            noGudang LIKE '%$search%' or
                                                                                            nilai LIKE '%$search%' or
                                                                                            jenis LIKE '%$search%' or
                                                                                            sp LIKE '%$search%' or
                                                                                            setor LIKE '%$search%' or
                                                                                            spj LIKE '%$search%' or
                                                                                            noverif LIKE '%$search%' or
                                                                                            ppk LIKE '%$search%' or
                                                                                            verif LIKE '%$search%' or
                                                                                            bayar LIKE '%$search%'");
           $datacount = $querycount->fetch_array();
           $totalFiltered = $datacount['jumlah'];
        }

        $data = array();
        if(!empty($query))
        {
            $no = $start + 1;
            while ($r = $query->fetch_array())
            {
                $nestedData['no'] = $no;
                $nestedData['tipe'] = $r['tipe'];
                $nestedData['pbf'] = $r['pbf'];
                $nestedData['tanggal'] = $r['tanggal'];
                $nestedData['faktur'] = $r['faktur'];
                $nestedData['noGudang'] = $r['noGudang'];
                $nestedData['nilai'] = $r['nilai'];
                $nestedData['jenis'] = $r['jenis'];
                $nestedData['sp'] = $r['sp'];
                $nestedData['setor'] = $r['nama'];
                $nestedData['spj'] = $r['spj'];
                $nestedData['noverif'] = $r['noverif'];
                $nestedData['ppk'] = $r['ppk'];
                $nestedData['verif'] = $r['verif'];
                $nestedData['bayar'] = $r['bayar'];
                $nestedData['aksi'] = "<a href='#' class='btn-warning btn-sm'>Ubah</a>&nbsp; <a href='#' class='btn-danger btn-sm'>Hapus</a>";
                $data[] = $nestedData;
                $no++;
            }
        }
          
        $json_data = array(
                    "draw"            => intval($_POST['draw']),  
                    "recordsTotal"    => intval($totalData),  
                    "recordsFiltered" => intval($totalFiltered), 
                    "data"            => $data   
                    );
            
        echo json_encode($json_data); 

}

This is koneksi.php:
    <?php
$host   = "localhost";
$user   = "root";
$pass   = "";
$db     = "project1db";

$mysqli = new mysqli($host, $user, $pass, $db);

?>

Tried Running and modificating the columns but nothing works.
the error persists:


Welcome to Stack Overflow. The error means that the JSON that is coming back, from the AJAX call, is malformed. You will want to monitor your Network console to see what is being submitted and returned by your script.

@Twisty i'm quite new to web developing, and sorry if this question seems silly to you, but how do i exactly monitor my network console?

This will depend on your browser. Most browsers have a Console or Development tool. When you view it there should be a Network section or tab that will show you HTTP activity, such as POST actions. You can review the data sent and the response payload. This can be very helpful when troubleshooting issues like this.
